# Neo4j Cypher query for finding nodes based on characteristics deltas

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my Neo4j/Spring Data Neo4j 4 project I have an entities: `Product`

every `Product` has an `Integer` property - `price`

For example I have a following products with prices:

```
Product1.price = 100
Product2.price = 305
Product3.price = 10000
Product4.price = 1000
Product5.price = 220
```

Products are not connected between each other with a relationships.

I need based on initial price value(Cypher query parameter) find a set(path) of products that distinct each other by a maximum price delta(Cypher query parameter).

For example I need to find all products in Neo4j database starting from price = 50 and price delta = 150. As an output I expect to get the following products:

```
Product1.price = 100
Product5.price = 220
Product2.price = 305
```

The computation looks like:

Starting point price = 50 so the first product should have a price not less than 50 and not more that 200(50+150). So based on this we found a product from our catalog with a price = 100. The second product should have a price not less than 100 and not more than 250(100+150).. This a product with a price = 220.. and the third price not less than 220 and not more 370. This is a product with a price = 305

Could you please show a Cypher query that will find such kind of products.

Comment: Can you clarify how price and price delta factor into your computation? My assumption was that you wanted to start with price, and the delta would give you a floor and ceiling of price -/+ the delta, but that would mean the ceiling would be 200 (50 + 150). The prices in your output exceed that, so my assumption is wrong, but I can't tell what calculation you want to use.

Comment: Something like that ?  
WITH 50 AS initPrice, 150 AS delta
WITH 
 CASE
     WHEN (initPrice-delta) > 0 THEN (initPrice-delta)
        ELSE 0
    END AS lowRange,
    (initPrice+delta) AS highRange
MATCH (n:Product)
WHERE lowRange < n.price < highRange
RETURN n

Comment: That seems to match my assumption, but the values in the prices in your example output don't fit that formula (prices of 220 and 305 are both higher than the calculated limit of 200). If this is just a problem in your example output, could you fix it to avoid confusion?

Comment: Thanks for your answers - I updated my question with a detailed computation algorithm

Comment: Thanks, the added detail makes this much clearer.

Comment: Why product with price = 10000 not in output?

Comment: @stdob-- If I'm reading the requirements correctly, the resulting products should have prices that are within the delta of the previous product. Product 2 has price 305, but there is no subsequent product within that delta (305 + 150).

Comment: because the price of this product is more than last product price + delta

Comment: @alexanoid Is it true that the initial list of products ordered? How?

Comment: The result list of products should be ordered by price(ASC). The initial list of products.. in other words - all products in the catalog is not ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternate solution which should be much faster to query, but requires more maintenance and care to keep working properly (especially with rapidly changing product price data), you can create relationships between your Product nodes in ascending price order, and keep the deltas as relationship properties.

Here's how you might create this using APOC Procedures:

```
MATCH (p:Product)
WITH p 
ORDER BY p.price ASC
WITH apoc.coll.pairsMin(COLLECT(p)) as products
UNWIND products as prodPairs
WITH prodPairs[0] as prod1, prodPairs[1] as prod2
CREATE (prod1)-[r:NextProd]->(prod2)
SET r.delta = prod2.price - prod1.price
```

And here's how you might query this once it's set up.

```
WITH {startPrice:50, delta:150} as params
WITH params, params.startPrice + params.delta as ceiling
MATCH (start:Product)
WHERE params.startPrice <= start.price <= ceiling
WITH start, params
ORDER BY start.price ASC
LIMIT 1
MATCH (start)-[r:NextProd*0..]->(product:Product)
WHERE ALL(rel in r WHERE rel.delta <= params.delta)
RETURN DISTINCT product
```

This should be a fairly fast query, as the ALL() predicate should cut off the variable match when it reaches a relationship that exceeds the desired delta.

The downside, of course, is that you'll need to make sure every operation that will impact this linked list structure (adding or removing products and changing product prices) properly adjusts the structure, and you might need to consider locking approaches to ensure threadsafety so you don't mangle the linked list if products and/or prices update concurrently.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this is the best way to go right now

Comment: The main issue with this approach that I can't jump over some of the products in this list or even traverse different paths based on different condition in query.. For example if I'd like to add some additional condition to price.. like WHERE product.color = 'red' then this approach, looks like will not work

Comment: You won't be able to jump over products, but you can add additional conditions, including on the nodes themselves. In the ALL() function, append this at the end: ` AND endNode(rel).color = 'red'`. This will add the additional requirement that all products in the path must be red.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather complex to perform in Cypher. The only approach that comes to me is to use the REDUCE() function along with a CASE statement to conditionally add the product to the end of the list if it is within the delta of price of the last product in the list.

Keep in mind that there is no way to short-circuit the processing of products with this approach. If there are 1 million total products, and we find in the ordered list of products that only the first two products are within that delta pattern, this query will continue to check every single remaining one of those million products, although none of them will be added to our list.

This query should work for you.

```
WITH {startPrice:50, delta:150} as params
MATCH (p:Product)
WHERE p.price >= params.startPrice
WITH params, p
ORDER BY p.price asc
WITH params, COLLECT(p) as products
WITH params, TAIL(products) as products, HEAD(products) as first
WHERE first.price <= params.startPrice + params.delta
WITH REDUCE(prods = [first], prod in products | 
  CASE WHEN prod.price <= LAST(prods).price + params.delta 
       THEN prods + prod 
       ELSE prods END) as products
RETURN products
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Is any way to optimize this schema in order to not impact the performance while looking for a product. Maybe add some kinds of relationships when creating a new Product in catalog or something else ? The performance is one of the important criteria in this system.

Comment: The only optimization I can think of using that route is to connect products in ascending order of price, and to set a delta property on each of those relationships as the delta between the prices of the nodes connected. That will let you perform an efficient variable-length match using ALL() to ensure all relationship deltas in the path are below your delta parameter, but this will be maintenance heavy if prices change or products are removed or inserted regularly. I can add this as a separate answer if you want more detail.

Answer (score 1):

The solution requires the transfer of an intermediate result during iteration. An interesting problem, because today cypher does not offer this possibility directly. As an exercise (sketch) use the `apoc.periodic.commit` procedure from [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_commit)-library:

```
CALL apoc.create.uuid() YIELD uuid
CALL apoc.periodic.commit("
  MERGE (H:tmpVars {id: {tmpId}})
  ON CREATE SET H.prices = [],
                H.lastPrice = {lastPrice}, 
                H.delta = {delta} 
  WITH H
  MATCH (P:Product) WHERE P.price > H.lastPrice AND 
                          P.price < H.lastPrice + H.delta
  WITH H, max(P.price) as lastPrice
  SET H.lastPrice = lastPrice, 
      H.prices = H.prices + lastPrice
  RETURN 1
  ", {tmpId: uuid, delta: 150, lastPrice: 50}
) YIELD updates, executions, runtime
MATCH (T:tmpVars {id: uuid}) 
WITH T, T.prices as prices DETACH DELETE T
WITH prices 
UNWIND prices as price
MATCH (P:Product) WHERE P.price = price
RETURN P ORDER BY P.price ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please also comment this aswer from the performance point of view? How this aproach depends on the products number in database ?

Comment: @alexanoid Sorry. This is just a sketch, an idea. No performance :)